# Get previous page URL a user has visited and add class to element on current page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the previous page URL a user has visited and then apply an "active" class to an element on the current page using jQuery.

My website sells telephone numbers so if a user visits a page that sells 0800 numbers then goes to the shop page I want my 0800 anchor link to have an active class

Here is what I have...

```
$("#range a").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == document.referrer) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

but the class isn't adding. Is document.referrer the correct way to grab the previous URL?

Thanks

Comment: Log both values that you are comparing there to console, and see if your expectation actually matches reality.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue when comparing them. Try using "===" or make them both toString() before comparing

Comment: okay so i just realized the URLs are different so that's why it isn't working. thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used CBroe's method of Logging both values to the console, and checking to see if the expectation actually matched reality. It turned out the URLs we're different so that's why I wasn't getting an expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using relative paths in your links. `document.referrer` returns an absolute path. Note that `#` fragments can also be different among other things that can make the comparison return false. Maybe you should parse `document.referrer` using the next trick to compare properly with your link href.

https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561